# Web app with out SSL integration intercepted by Proxy

Tags: http, ssl, https, proxy

My application is based on Spring framework  and is used to transmit very confidential data.During testing of the application with with proxy tools like Fiddler, Paros Proxy etc. it was found that these tools are intercepting the request data, and data is easily modified before reaching the server.

My application is not currently not integrated with SSL . We will implement SSL /HTTPS. but is this because SSL has not been integrated ?

Is it normal for Proxy tools to intercept the data from a web application with out HTTPS ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here.

1) If you don't use SSL the communication is not encrypted, which means that anybody who is able to intercept the traffic, will be able to see the content. You don't necessarily need a proxy for that.

2) With an intercepting HTTP proxy you can see SSL encrypted traffic as well. What the proxy does is building two separate SSL tunnels one between the server and the proxy and one between the client and the proxy. This way the proxy itself can see the whole traffic. Of course the proxy can only provide a fake SSL certificate which will trigger a notification in the browser for the user, but he will probably ignore it.

Comment: So using http is there is no security at all for confidential data? Only when data security is not a criteria, we go for http?

Comment: It depends how you use HTTP. In rich/fat clients, you can enforce strict certificate validation to reject fake certs.
In browsers the browser will warn the user in various ways but you cannot do much more on the server-side except to use a certificate signed by a well known certificate authority which is included in all browsers.

@bummi thanks for the link.

Comment: @gerion, maybe you could edit some of you answers to avoid to get in trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you don't use https, Proxy see everything that the application send or received.

To prevent that, you must use https.

To prevent sslstrip you must use HSTS.